# Pdf.js issue with dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf.js

I include pdf.js as :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.js"></script>
```

In my js I created html for my page (want show first page on pdf files).

```
$('#favBoardSecondPopupPagesInfo').html('<div class="pdfDiv ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" style="position: relative;"><a target="_blank" href="/favDocuments/tmpFile_1.pdf"><img class="pdfImageFirstPage" data-pdf-thumbnail-width="100" data-pdf-thumbnail-height="200" data-pdf-thumbnail-file="/favDocuments/tmpFile_1.pdf"></a></div>');
```

But when I add pages dynamicly it doesnt work. If I add code right to html when load page it works. 
How can I solve this? Thanks.

It is my popup in html:

```
 <div class="g-hidden">
        <div class="box-modal ui-widget-content" id="favBoardSecondPopup">
            <div class="box-modal_close arcticmodal-close"><img id="closePopupImage"
                                                                src="/images/icons/popup_icon_close.png">
            </div>

            <div id="favBoardSecondPopupLeadsInfo"></div>

            <div id="favBoardSecondPopupPagesInfo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In js I run ajax, and generate content:

```
var filesAmount = data.filesAmount;
                var pdfStr = '';
                for(var j=1;j<=filesAmount;j++){
                    pdfStr+='<div class="pdfDiv"><a  target="_blank" href="/favDocuments/tmpFile_'+j+'.pdf"><img  class="pdfImageFirstPage" data-pdf-thumbnail-width="100" data-pdf-thumbnail-height="200" data-pdf-thumbnail-file="/favDocuments/tmpFile_'+j+'.pdf"></a></div>';
                }
                $('#favBoardSecondPopupPagesInfo').html(pdfStr);
```

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am missing your HTML Code but have you included the JQuery script as you are working with jquery functions?
You can read how to include JQuery here: [Get started with Jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)
OR easily include it into your head:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

If you do that the html gets generated into a div:

```
<div id="favBoardSecondPopupPagesInfo">
</div>
```

Have you added a div with that id to your HTML Code?

EDIT:

With the given HTML and JS Code I get a Reference Error because data is not defined. If I change the variable filesAmount to e.g. 4 it works perfectly fine and 4 pdfs get added as HTML Code into the div #favBoardSecondPopupPagesInfo. So I guess you defined the variable wrong. If data is an array use: data.length instead.

```
var filesAmount = 4;

                var pdfStr = '';
                for(var j=1;j<=filesAmount;j++){
                    pdfStr+='<div class="pdfDiv"><a  target="_blank" href="/favDocuments/tmpFile_'+j+'.pdf"><img  class="pdfImageFirstPage" data-pdf-thumbnail-width="100" data-pdf-thumbnail-height="200" data-pdf-thumbnail-file="/favDocuments/tmpFile_'+j+'.pdf"></a></div>';
                }
                $('#favBoardSecondPopupPagesInfo').html(pdfStr);
```

Comment: Yes, i all added , and jquery, and html to page. problem is that when i added #favBoardSecondPopupPagesInfo content dynamicly it doesn't show first  page of my pdf. If i work content right to html it works.

Comment: I added my html and js